# Flannel-Wrapper unable to resolve UUID: no such file

Tags: coreos, flannel

After installing coreos (stable, beta or alpha) I can't start flanneld.service because of the dependency flannel-docker-opts.service fails.  It's giving an error about

> rm: unable to resolve the UUID from file: open
>   /var/lib/coreos/flannel-wrapper2.uuid: no such file or directory

I'm new to coreos and am trying to install kubernetes on it; for that I have a separate etcd cluster stood up with SSL certs for them.  I have an etcd proxy on the image up and running but flannel wont start for docker to run.

I'm not sure if I'm suppose to be including more configuration in my cloud-config to fix this or not.  I can't seem to find anything on flannel-wrapper or flannel-docker-opts.service

Here's my cloud-config.yaml

```
#cloud-config

write_files:

  - path: /run/systemd/system/etcd2.service.d/30-certificates.conf
    permissions: 0644
    content: |
      [Service]
      Environment="ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/client.pem"
      Environment="ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/client-key.pem"
      Environment="ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
      Environment="ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/client.pem"
      Environment="ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/client-key.pem"
      Environment="ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem"
      # Listen only on loopback interface.
      Environment="ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://127.0.0.1:4001"

hostname: "Kube-MST1"

ssh_authorized_keys:
  - "ssh-rsa AAAAB3N....

coreos:
  etcd2:
    proxy: on
    listen-client-urls: "http://127.0.0.1:2379"
    initial-cluster: "ETCD1=http://192.168.1.7:2380,ETCD2=http://192.168.1.8:2380,ETCD3=http://192.168.1.9:2380"

  fleet:
    public-ip: "192.168.1.10"
    metadata: "region=us-east"
    etcd_servers: "http://127.0.0.1:2379"
    etcd_cafile: /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
    etcd_certfile: /etc/ssl/etcd/client.pem
    etcd_keyfile: /etc/ssl/etcd/client-key.pem

  flannel:
    etcd_prefix: "/coreos.com/network"
    etcd_endpoints: "http://127.0.0.1:2379"
    public-ip: "192.168.1.10"
    interface: "192.168.1.10"
    etcd_cafile: /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
    etcd_certfile: /etc/ssl/etcd/client.pem
    etcd_keyfile: /etc/ssl/etcd/client-key.pem

  update:
    reboot-strategy: "etcd-lock"

  units:
    - name: 00-ens192.network
      runtime: true
      content: |
        [Match]
        Name=ens192

        [Network]
        DNS=192.168.1.100
        DNS=192.168.1.101
        Address=192.168.1.10/24
        Gateway=192.168.1.1

    - name: flanneld.service
      command: start
      drop-ins:
        - name: 50-network-config.conf
          content: |
            [Service]
            ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl --endpoints http://127.0.0.1:2379 \ --ca-file /etc/ssl/etcd/ca.pem --cert-file /etc/ssl/etcd/client.pem --key-file /etc/ssl/etcd/client-key.pem \ set /coreos.com/network/config '{ "Network": "10.0.0.0/16" }'

    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start

    - name: fleet.service
      command: start

    - name: docker.service
      drop-ins:
        - name: "50-insecure-registry.conf"
          content: |
            [Service]
            Environment=DOCKER_OPTS='--insecure-registry="proxy.test.lab:8081"'

    - name: docker.service
      drop-ins:
       - name: 51-docker-mirror.conf
         content: |
           [Unit]
           Requires=flanneld.service
           After=flanneld.service
           Restart=always
         command: start

    - name: kubelet-unit.service
      command: start
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Requires=flanneld.service
        After=flanneld.service

        [Service]
        Environment=KUBELET_VERSION=v1.5.3_coreos.0
        Environment="RKT_OPTS=--uuid-file-save=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid \
          --volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log \
          --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log \
          --volume dns,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf \
          --mount volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf"
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/containers
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid
        ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
          --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 \
          --register-schedulable=false \
          --cni-conf-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d \
          --container-runtime=docker \
          --allow-privileged=true \
          --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
          --hostname-override= 192.168.1.10 \
          --cluster_dns= 10.9.0.100 \
          --cluster_domain=cluster.local
        ExecStop=-/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid
        Restart=always
        RestartSec=10

        [Install]
        WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Any progress? I have a similar problem

Comment: I have someone on github posted that the uuid problem shouldn't be a problem and I think I found something else that may be wrong with it trying to connect to "public.update.core-os.net" for some reason.  I'm on a closed network so I'm thinking maybe thats the reason why it wont start.
https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/626

Comment: So opening the firewall didn't seem to do anything... : \